# How to compare text in a case insensitive way on OSX Yosemite

Tags: macos, delphi, locale, firemonkey, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to compare two strings on OSX in a case insensitive way using AnsiSameText. This used to work fine, but on OSX Yosemite this behaves strange if the "preferred language" of OSX is set to **Dutch** ("System Preferences" -> "Language & Region" -> "Preferred languages" -> "Nederlands Dutch").

In the following code sample I'd expect that it only prints "same". But I get "same, different, different".

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

begin
  if AnsiSameText('abcde', 'ABCDE') then // Same
    WriteLn('Same')
  else
    WriteLn('Different');

  if AnsiSameText('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') then // different
    WriteLn('Same')
  else
    WriteLn('Different');

  if AnsiSameText('i', 'I') then // different
    WriteLn('Same')
  else
    WriteLn('Different');
end.
```

What is the correct way to compare the texts in a case insensitive way?

I'm using Delphi XE7.

Comment: That behaviour is clearly wrong. Do you get the same output on different versions of Delphi? Different versions of OSX? What happens when you debug `AnsiSameText`. You do have the source code for it.

Comment: When debugging into AnsiSameText `CFStringCompareWithOptionsAndLocale` returns -1. 

On OSX 10.9 AnsiSameText works as expected. I tried XE5 and XE7, it fails on both versions. As soon as I change the language of OSX 10.10 to English, AnsiSameText works as expected. But I cannot tell my Dutch users to switch the language of their OS.

Comment: Next step is to write an Obj-C program that passes these strings to `CFStringCompareWithOptionsAndLocale` and try to narrow down exactly where the problem lies. It sounds a little as though the OSX version change is the key here. But it could be that the Delphi wrapper around `CFStringCompareWithOptionsAndLocale` has always been broken and the new version just happens to highlight the flaw. You might also submit your example program to the Delphi quality portal to give Emba a chance to look at the issue. Btw, +1 for a superb MCVE.

Comment: I might look at the use of `UTF8CompareLocale` in the call to `CFStringCompareWithOptionsAndLocale`. I wonder what happens if you pass `nil` instead of `UTF8CompareLocale`.

Comment: It works when passing nil or CFLocaleGetSystem. But does that introduce other issues?

Comment: I don't know enough about this subject. I don't understand why Emba choose to use something other than `nil` here.

Comment: I suppose that the ANSI functions are there for backward compatibility, as everyting is Unicode now? Anyway, have you tried the string helper compare functions, which also allows you to specify a locale? (e.g. Strings.compare(Str1,Str2,true))

Comment: @Hans No. The functions are poorly named. They are the locale aware comparison functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delphi initializes UTF8CompareLocale with the value returned from CFLocaleCopyCurrent. UTF8CompareLocale is used inside AnsiSameText for the locale settings that are used for the case insensitive comparison. But then OSX Yosemite considers "I" and "i" different if the language of OSX is set to Dutch.

Calling `SetUTF8CompareLocale('en_US');` on a Dutch system fixes the problem without having to patch the Delphi units.

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem. It just makes your program use English locale. Why don't you use the default locale.

Comment: I'd have to patch System.SysUtils for that. If I pass nil or CFLocaleGetSystem then OSX uses the English sort order, too. (try comparing "ait" and "aIt" with Turkish as primary language). As soon as the Dutch sort order is used, i and I are different letters. So that is obviously not an option.